# After creating a dataframe from a hive table, if the data in the table is altered, will the dataframe contain new data or old data?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, immutability

Data gets loaded into dataframe when an action is performed on it.
But before performing any action and after creating it from a hive table, if the data in the table is modified, will the changes be reflected in the dataframe?

Comment: transformations means a new immutable states. Unless you initialized the initial dataframe as mutable and changed it, the dataframe won't get changed.

Comment: that means, even if the table contents are changed, dataframe still has old data?

Comment: if you don't use mutable transformations such as .withColumn.

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe will not contain the old data, because the dataframe does not contain any data at all. a dataframe is nothing more than a "query plan", not materalized data.

In your case, I would say that you get your new data or alternatively a `FileNotFoundException` if spark has already cached hive table metadata and filenames and these things changed with the new data.